# acharEngine Donut having Extra show in android , How to remove them?

Tags: android, achartengine, donut-chart

I am using achartEngine Library to draw donut in my android application . But creating my donut I'm getting `0 1 2` as am creating 3 donut . I go with only one donut then get only `1` after donut..is there any method in achartEngine to remove them.Plase find Image.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the legend:

```
renderer.setShowLegend(false);
```